# How to implement a non-intrusive UI element in Intellij editor

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I would like to implement something similar to breakpoint or lightbulb notifications in my IntelliJ plugin. Up until now I've been using `Inlay` which is great but they shift the text next to them. I need something similar that doesn't impact text layout and can still receive user clicks.

It would also be great if I can place such content in the gutter area like real breakpoints.

Unfortunately these things are very hard to search for as the common keywords popup up and cloud the search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I was looking for are gutter icons: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000164564-Insert-Gutter-icon